# Google Analytics : Funnel what to add in Category Label and Actions

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am quite new to analytics I am product manager but I have always used GA for Websites.
My new Job demands me to create funnels for Mobile apps which have event tracking in place.
The screen names are: Home | Settings | Popovers screen | Side drawer
Now when I go in Funnel to create it I choose Events and it ask me to add
majorly two things : Category, Action, Label and Value which I have not idea what to add

Example I want to check How many users actually landed on Home and then click on Side drawer and then went to settings ..

This is the flow .. can anyone please help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Question is about creating Funnels in the Google Analytics application and is not programing related.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a funnel based on events, first you need details regarding each and every individual events. But here I think what you need to create is a funnel based on the page views (destination page).

For example, first step of your funnel would be landing on the home page. Second the second page, settings page etc. First choose your destination page and start to create a goal for that selected destination page. Then under that enable funnel option and add desired page sequence one by one.

This will create the funnel. But this won't show any click events as it based on pageviews.

Comment: Thanks but I think you are talking in terms of a Web I need this for a Mobile app and in Events we need to add Category Action and labels